# psycopg2: Insert a numpy array of strings into an PostgreSQL table

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, database, postgresql

Please consider me to be a complete novice with psycopg2. My aim is to insert a 1D numpy array of dtype object (where the elements are only strings) into a postgresQL table. My main program saves the fields as strings in the numpy array. I then want to add each separate element  to a column in the postgresqL table (or if you prefer, the the 1d Array is one row). Please note, the actual array has 36 elements! I need a method to put them all in.

I am using the cur.execute command although I believe there is some problem with the string conversion.

```
Array=np.empty(3,dype=object)
Array[0]='Hello'
Array[1]='Tea?'
Array[2]='Bye'

statement= "INSERT INTO testlog (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (%s)" #Etc.
cur.execute(statement,Array)
```

I get error:

```
cur.execute(statement,Array)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Also tried:

```
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO testlog VALUES ( %s )', [[v] for v in Array ]
```

Thanks

Comment: @Clodoaldo You are right, read about it just now [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#problems-with-type-conversions)

Answer (score 1):

Your statement should contain place holder for all values:

```
statement= "INSERT INTO testlog (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
```

For Example:

```
=# create table testlog (field1 varchar(50), field2 varchar(50), field3 varchar(50))`;
```

then in the python shell (note `dtype` not `dype`:

```
Array=np.empty(3,dtype=object)
Array[0]='Hello'
Array[1]='Tea?'
Array[2]='Bye'
sql = "INSERT INTO testlog (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
cur.execute(sql, [f for f in Array])
conn.commit()
```

And in DB:

```
select * from testlog;
 field1 | field2 | field3 
--------+--------+--------
 Hello  | Tea?   | Bye
(1 row)
```